# StackOverflowError - Java

Tags: java, regex, stack-overflow

I want to remove all multi-line comments from Java code, I'm using the following REGEX at the moment which is causing a `StackOverflowError`.

`String regexMultiLine = "(?<!\"/)(/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/)";`

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4569)`

I'm using the above REGEX with the following code:

`content = content.replaceAll(regexMultiLine,"");`

I want remove all commented out code in the file. There are instances were there is `"//*`  which is not the start of a comment which I don't want to be removed.

How can I rework this REGEX so it doesn't cause this issue?

Comment: Might be easier to implement a simple FSM instead of trying to use a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your program doesn't need a lot of total memory (one source file can't be that large). Have you tried increasing the stack size using -Xss123m  (where 123 can be whatever value you need)? Assuming your regex works (have you tried it on a few very simple test cases) and it's just having trouble on a larger file, I'd suggest testing some increases to the stack size and see if there's a point within reason where it allows it to finish.

Comment: It seems to work for some files but not for others and I've no control of the files which can change in size and number.

Comment: Then I'd definitely suggest just upping the stack size.

Comment: Even though the upper limit will never be known?

Comment: Sure, there's no actual upper limit. But there's got to be a fairly practical maximum file size that you can target. If you have a working regex, it's easier than the alternatives of re-writing that part of the code.